# if i have a data in highcharts greater then 1000 i want to display 1k

Tags: highcharts

I have a facing problem when I have a data greater then 1000 it will make graph disturbing so I want to decrease it if it is greater the 1000 it started going to show 1k at the top of the bar in high charts

you can see it on below link 
[my code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxmQvw#anon-login)

```
Highcharts.chart('container',{chart:{type:'bar'},
title:{text:'Historic World Population by Region'},
subtitle:{text:'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Wikipedia.org</a>'},
xAxis:{categories:['Africa','America','Asia','Europe','Oceania'], 
title:{text:null}}, yAxis:{min:0,title:{text:'Population (millions)', align:'high'}, 
labels:{overflow:'justify'}}, tooltip:{valueSuffix:' millions'},
plotOptions:{bar:{dataLabels:{enabled:true}}},legend:{layout:'vertical',align:'right',verticalAlign:'top', 
x:-40,y:80,floating:true,borderWidth:1,
backgroundColor:((Highcharts.theme&&Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor)||'#FFFFFF'), shadow:true},
credits:{enabled:false},
series:[{name:'Year 1800',data:[107,31,635,203,2]},{name:'Year 1900',data:[133,156,947,408,6]},
{name:'Year 2000',data:[814,841,3714,727,31]},
{name:'Year 2016',data:[1216,1001,4436,738,40]}]});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess your data and replace `y` values:

```
var series = [...];

series.forEach(function(s) {
    s.data.forEach(function(point, i) {
        if (point >= 1000) {
            s.data[i] = {
                y: 1000,
                realValue: point
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If you want to display the real values, you can store them and show in a tooltip and data labels:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function(tooltip) {
            if (this.point.realValue) {
                return '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + this.x + '</span><br/>' +
                    '<span style="color:' + this.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + this.series.name + ': <b>' + this.point.realValue + '</b><br/>';
            }
            // If not null, use the default formatter
            return tooltip.defaultFormatter.call(this, tooltip);
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.point.realValue ? this.point.realValue : this.y
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: series
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/18fe7yrw/

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.dataLabels.formatter

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter